# Finding anomalies for millions of records

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, deep-learning, anomaly-detection

i have a database (more then 2M rows) that contains 4 columns:

1. PC
2. User
3. Date
4. Count

The 'Count' columns is aggregate base on (PC + User + Date)
*t's how many specific user visit specific computer in specific day*
So for example:

| PC | USER | Date | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | a | 2020-01-01 | 5 |
| A | a | 2020-01-02 | 8 |
| A | b | 2020-02-04 | 5 |
| B | b | 2020-01-01 | 5 |
| B | c | 2020-02-04 | 5 |

For row number one:
User a Connected to PC A 5 time in 2020-01-01
etc....

i created an algorithm that take every ' combination' and calculate the isolation forest

```
def isolationForest_group(group_count):
    scaler = standardscaler()
    np_scaler = scaler.fit_transform(group_count.values.reshape(-1,1)
    data = pd.DataFrame(np_scaler)
    model = IsolationForest()
    model.fir(data)
    return model.predict(data)

df['Anomaly_ISO') = df.groupby(['PC','USER'])['Count'].transform(isolationForest_group)
```

but its not Efficient there is a way to make it better (Reduce the time it takes to run )???
The algorithm does not have to be a isolationForest algorithm
the end result should look like that:

| PC | USER | Date | Count | Anomaly |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | a | 2020-01-01 | 5 | 0 |
| A | a | 2020-01-02 | 8 | 0 |
| A | a | 2020-01-03 | 500 | 1 |
| A | a | 2020-01-04 | 5 | 0 |
| A | a | 2020-02-04 | 5 | 0 |
| A | b | 2020-02-01 | 5 | 0 |
| A | b | 2020-02-02 | 800 | 1 |
| A | b | 2020-02-04 | 5 | 0 |
| A | b | 2020-03-01 | 5 | 0 |
| A | b | 2020-03-04 | 5 | 0 |
| C | a | 2020-01-01 | 4 | 0 |
| C | a | 2020-01-02 | 100 | 1 |
| C | a | 2020-01-03 | 5 | 0 |

So first the algorithm take ALL dates for the combination of PC A and User a and All Dates for combination A with user b and so on....

Answer (score 0):

I can propose the statistic method, not ML, it works really fast, but I don't know if it will work for you. You can use the same formula used in [boxplots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot) for anomaly detection. You can set the sensitivity of the method by increasing or decreasing IQR multiplier. So your code can look like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#exporting your df
q1,q3 = np.quantile(df['Count'], [.25,.75])
iqr = q3 - q1

df['Anomaly'] = df['Count'] > (q3 + 1.5 *iqr)
```

The result:
[image]